# How to create usercontrol using Gridview and Textbox in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I wanted to create a usercontrol in WPF using a gridview and a textbox.

I wanted to show data on the textbox when a row is selected in the gridview.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: have you found it useful or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Find Solution  as below :

UserControl XAML  Code

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.DataGridControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="15*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="85*"></RowDefinition>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>  
        <TextBox x:Name="txtvalue" Width="100" Grid.Row="0" />
        <DataGrid x:Name="dg" SelectionChanged="dg_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Usercontrol Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for DataGridControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class DataGridControl : UserControl
    {
        public DataGridControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
            dt.Columns.Add("Column2");

            dt.Rows.Add("Ashok", "Rathod");
            dt.Rows.Add("Paresh", "Jadav");
            dt.Rows.Add("Keyur", "Kamdar");

            dt.AcceptChanges();

            dg.DataContext = dt;
        }

        private void dg_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView obj = dg.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
            if(obj != null)
            { 
                txtvalue.Text=Convert.ToString(obj.Row["Column1"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow Xaml  for use of usercontrol

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControlMainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="UserControlMainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <uc:DataGridControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: But, How can create the dynamic ItemsSource. I mean that, "<UC:DataGridControl ItemsSource={Binding Path=Mydata} " thanks.

Comment: you can change the itemsource to any collection source and accordingly u have to change the your code of selectionchanged as per source.

Comment: But how to create ItemsSource Property in this usercontrol? thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic requirement description. You can try to create a user control and add a gridview control and a text box which is straight forward.
Then use SelectedIndexChange event of the gridview to select and display the values in the selected row. Once you try this, if it's failing, post the code.

Comment: I am not sure why you have accepted this as answer while the following answer by Ashok seems to be a direct help to you. I have just guided you, not given any code :)